# Duplicated logs Flask - Google Cloud Logging

Tags: python-3.x, flask, logging, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I'm developing a web application in Flask, using GAE.
My issue here is: Every time that my application tries to log, i got multiple entries on log file:
[log viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9gIX.png)
.
My dbconnection class only imports a default logger class that i created and calls *unexpected_error_log()* to write whenever it needed.

My logger class:

```
import logging
from google.cloud import logging as cloudlogging

class LoggerDB:
    def __init__(self):
        log_client = cloudlogging.Client()
        log_handler = log_client.get_default_handler()
        self.cloud_logger = logging.getLogger("cloudLogger")
        self.cloud_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.cloud_logger.addHandler(log_handler)

    def unexpected_error_log(self, name, error="Unhandled Exception"):
        self.cloud_logger.error("Unexpected Error on %s: %s", name, error)
```

Code when executed:

```
def insertVenda(self, venda):
    try:
        query = "xxxxx"
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        self.connection.commit()
        return "Success"
    except Exception as error:
        self.logger.unexpected_error_log(__name__, error)
        self.connection.rollback()
        return "Error"
```

I suspect that gunicorn/app logging is duplicating my logs, but i don't know how to handle this case.
Did someone had the same problem?

Comment: Show the code where the log messages are generated.

Comment: edited on question...

Comment: The code for importing the logs to Stackdriver Logging seems to be correct. I would
suggest to look at your code, to see if there is anything else that can be causing
these logs.

Comment: could gunicorn be duplicating my logs? is there a way to shutdown logs from gunicorn?

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with this at the moment, my suspicion at the moment if you include something like this:

```
# Imports Python standard library logging
import logging

import google.cloud.logging

# Instantiates a client
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()

# Retrieves a Cloud Logging handler based on the environment
# you're running in and integrates the handler with the
# Python logging module. By default this captures all logs
# at INFO level and higher
client.get_default_handler()
client.setup_logging()
```

I get logs OK, but multiple duplicates.
If I omit I just get single stdout print statements going to the stackdriver logs.

Comment: The problem is dublicate logs, your answer doesn't solve that.